# Multiple Bathymetry Layers, How to group into one?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, bathymetry

I'm an extreme novice to GIS.

I'm using ArcGIS (Arcmap) and basically I've got 5 bathymetry layers, and I'm just wondering how to group them into one. Which would allow them to be represented with graduated colour with association to depth, rather than each having a single colour.

Comment: Are your bathymetry layers contour lines, point depths, or something else?

Comment: They're polygons, with each having a discrete value of; 0, 200, 1000, 2000, 3000.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to revise it with any requested clarifications like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool called `Topo To Raster` (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Topo_to_Raster/00q90000000s000000/), you can generate a raster from contours. If you want to do this, you would first need to merge all your layers, just search for the merge tool in the arctoolbox. Here you can find similar solutions: http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=11337908

Comment: Brilliant, the merging tool worked perfection! Thankyou all

Comment: Glad to help you, please mark it as the answer if you find it useful =)